# Moderator stat highlighting not very visible

Tags: bug, design, css, moderator-tools

On the [moderator tools page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/admin), the "25% or less" highlighting is grey, like the rest of the text. It *is* bold, but I don't think that's really sufficient highlighting. I believe this used to be red before graduation.

[image]

Comment: Also, the "flags" column in the stats is harder to read. I'm not going to post a screenshot of that section since it's not a public page, but I thought I'd mention it. On beta sites, these are highlighted the same color as the icon-flag counter.

Comment: I don't remember seeing this during the Beta phase when I had access to the moderator tools. What does this statistic pertain to?

Comment: @JimG. That's from the diamond mod tools, not the 10k mod tools. It explains what the colors in individual mod stats mean.

Comment: @Yannis: Thank you.